# How to resume download in PYTHON, using urlretrieve function?

Tags: http, ftp, download, urllib2, resume-download

Can anyone tell me how to resume a download? I'm using urlretrieve function. If there is an interruption, the download restarts from the beginning. I want the program to read the size of localfile (which I m able to do) and then resume the download from that very byte onwards.