# Python URLRetrieve Limit Rate and Resume Partial Download

Tags: python, limit, rate, resume-download

I'm using the code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456649/throttling-with-urllib2) to limit my download rate.

How do I incorporate partial downloads resuming with the rate limiting code?  The examples I've found use `urlopen` instead of `urlretrieve`, and the `RateLimit` class depends on `urlretrieve`.

I'd like to have an external function that controls the partial downloading, without having to change the `RateLimit` class:

```
from throttle import TokenBucket, RateLimit

def retrieve_limit_rate(url, filename, rate_limit):
    """Fetch the contents of urls"""
    bucket = TokenBucket(10*rate_limit, rate_limit)

    print "rate limit = %.1f kB/s" % (rate_limit,)

    print 'Downloading %s...' % filename
    rate_limiter = RateLimit(bucket, filename)
    #
    # What do I put here to allow resuming files?
    #
    return urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename, rate_limiter)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resume download in PYTHON, using urlretrieve function??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581296/how-to-resume-download-in-python-using-urlretrieve-function) and [Download file using urllib in Python with the wget -c feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021519)

Comment: Not duplicates because: urllib.urlretrieve can limit the rate using class RateLimit.  urllib2.urlopen can resume files, but can't limit rate.  Need a way to combine both a rate limit and a file resume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be able to use PyCurl instead:

```
def curl_progress(total, existing, upload_t, upload_d):
    try:
        frac = float(existing)/float(total)
    except:
        frac = 0
    print "Downloaded %d/%d (%0.2f%%)" % (existing, total, frac)

def curl_limit_rate(url, filename, rate_limit):
    """Rate limit in bytes"""
    import pycurl
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    c.setopt(c.MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, rate_limit)
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        file_id = open(filename, "ab")
        c.setopt(c.RESUME_FROM, os.path.getsize(filename))
    else:
        file_id = open(filename, "wb")

    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, file_id)
    c.setopt(c.NOPROGRESS, 0)
    c.setopt(c.PROGRESSFUNCTION, curl_progress)
    c.perform()
```