# Bandwidth limit "urllib.request.urlopen" not "urllib.request.urlretrieve"

Tags: python

How to do that ?

For example I want to limit my urllib.request.urlopen download speed to 10KB/s or file upload speed to 10KB/s.

I already read all thread about bandwidth limit but there is no answer yet, all of them are about `urllib.request.urlretrieve`.

About urlopen and urlretrieve: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html

Answer for urllib.request.urlretrieve: [Throttling with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456649/throttling-with-urllib2)
[Python URLRetrieve Limit Rate and Resume Partial Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533304/python-urlretrieve-limit-rate-and-resume-partial-download)

Comment: could you be more clear

Comment: Okay, I will try to add more information.